# Scrapy only scrapes the first start url in a list of 15 start urls

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to Scrapy and am attempting to teach myself the basics. I have compiled a code that goes to the Louisiana Department of Natural Resources website to retrieve the serial number for certain oil wells.

I have each well's link listed in the start URLs command, but scrappy only downloads data from the first url. What am I doing wrong?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from mike.items import MikeItem

class SonrisSpider(Spider):
   name = "sspider"

   start_urls = [
    "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=207899",
    "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=971683",
    "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=214206",
    "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=159420",
    "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=243671",
    "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=248942",
    "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=156613",
    "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=972498",
    "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=215443",
    "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=248463",
    "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=195136",
    "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=179181",
    "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=199930",
    "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=203419",
    "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=220454",

]


    def parse(self, response):
       item = MikeItem()
       item['serial'] =    response.xpath('/html/body/table[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/text()').extract()[0]
       yield item
```

Thank you for any help you might be able to provide. If I have not explained my problem thoroughly, please let me know and I will attempt to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this code might help,

By default scrapy prevent duplicate requests. Since only the parameters are different in your start-url scrapy will consider the rest of the urls in the start-url as duplicate request of the first one. That's why your spider stops after fetching the first url. In order to parse the rest of the urls we have enable `dont_filter` flag in the scrapy request. (chek the `start_request()`)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
from mike.items import MikeItem


class SonrisSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "sspider"
    allowed_domains = ["sonlite.dnr.state.la.us"]
    start_urls = [
                "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=207899",
                "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=971683",
                "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=214206",
                "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=159420",
                "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=243671",
                "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=248942",
                "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=156613",
                "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=972498",
                "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=215443",
                "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=248463",
                "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=195136",
                "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=179181",
                "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=199930",
                "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=203419",
                "http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_wellinfo2?p_WSN=220454",
            ]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_data, dont_filter=True)

    def parse_data(self, response):
        item = MikeItem()
        serial = response.xpath(
            '/html/body/table[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/text()').extract()
        serial = serial[0] if serial else 'n/a'
        item['serial'] = serial
        yield item
```

sample output returned by this spider is as follows,

```
{'serial': u'207899'}
{'serial': u'971683'}
{'serial': u'214206'}
{'serial': u'159420'}
{'serial': u'248942'}
{'serial': u'243671'}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code sounds good, try to add this function

```
class SonrisSpider(Spider):
    def start_requests(self):
            for url in self.start_urls:
                print(url)
                yield self.make_requests_from_url(url)
    #the result of your code goes here
```

The URLs should be printed now. Test it, if not, say please

Comment: Thank you for your response! Im sorry, but I am so new that I dont know where this would go in the code? Would it go before the start URL line or immediately after? Also what do you mean when you say "and print something inside the for in order to check if each url is being called or not". Again, I am very new so I know these are probably basic and I apologize.

Comment: before the parse function. print as in print "Came here" below the yield function but in the for loop indentation

Comment: @JosiahHulsey smashed answered you. put it in anyplace inside your class. and print something inside the for like this: `print("Came here")`. maybe it is a good idea to spend sometime learning basics for python